# How to query for the difference between the sequences of two columns, from differing tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need a query that will compare the sequences of two columns (from two different tables) and display the first differing result. Summary with details follow:

- Operating out of a PostgreSQL server and using DBeaver
- Two tables with identical column headers.
- One entry (creq_id) will have 36 sequences (seq).
- When the UI modifies the data (chan_id), Table B records the new entry.

  - Modification can be a change to original value or a new addition to the sequence.
- Query should compare each sequence (total of 36 sequences) from both tables and stop at the first difference which is recorded in Table B.

Example of changing/overwriting a chan_id:

**Table A**

| creq_id | chan_id | seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29022 | 400 | 1 |
| 29022 | 0 | 2 |
| 29022 | 0 | 3 |

**Table B**

| creq_id | chan_id | seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29022 | 500 | 1 |
| 29022 | 0 | 2 |
| 29022 | 0 | 3 |

Example of adding a new chan_id

**Table A**

| creq_id | chan_id | seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29022 | 400 | 1 |
| 29022 | 0 | 2 |
| 29022 | 0 | 3 |

**Table B**

| creq_id | chan_id | seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29022 | 400 | 1 |
| 29022 | 500 | 2 |
| 29022 | 0 | 3 |

In either case above, the result I am seeking:

- Table A.chan_id as orig_value
- Table B.chan_id as new_value

| orig_value | new_value |
| --- | --- |
| 400 | 500 |

Comment: Remember that SQL is _generally_ not concerned with _ordered information_ - it's only concerned with unordered (mathematical) sets of tuples (this is demonstrated by the fact you can only have `ORDER BY` in your outermost query)  - so what you're asking is actually much harder than you may realize and isn't possible to solve using only ISO SQL - you'll need to use implementation-specific window functions like `LAG`.

Comment: Are you using 0 to mean "no entry"? Because in the second case there's no way to distinguish between changing seq 2 from 0 to 500 (orig: 0, new: 500) and adding seq 2 with a value of 500 (orig: 400, new: 500). It would be better to use null.

Comment: That column is set to NOT NULL, so we have 0 there to show it isn't populated.

Comment: @RichardConaway Could you remove that constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic query is to join each table by creq_id and seq_id, then check if their chan_ids are not equal.

To differentiate between a change and an add, if tableA's chan_id is 0 then it's a change and we need to use chan_id from the previous sequence. We get that with a subquery.

```
select
  a.creq_id,
  case a.chan_id
  when 0 then (
      -- Get the previous chan_id
      select chan_id
      from tablea
      where creq_id = a.creq_id
        and seq = a.seq - 1
  )
  else
      a.chan_id
  end as original,
  b.chan_id as new,
  a.seq,
  b.seq
from tablea a
join tableb b on a.creq_id = b.creq_id and a.seq = b.seq
where a.chan_id != b.chan_id
```

This causes a problem, what if you want to store a 0 then change it? It looks the same as having added a new value. To avoid this, use `null` instead of 0 to mean "no value".

```
select
  a.creq_id,
  coalesce(
      a.chan_id,
      (
        -- Get the previous chan_id
        select chan_id
        from tablea
        where creq_id = a.creq_id
          and seq = a.seq - 1
      )
  ) as original,
  b.chan_id as new,
  a.seq,
  b.seq
from tablea a
join tableb b on a.creq_id = b.creq_id and a.seq = b.seq
-- skip when both columns are null, because null != null
where (a.chan_id is null and b.chan_id is not null)
   or a.chan_id != b.chan_id
```

Comment: I am quite amazed at the accuracy and speed at which this community can answer the variety of questions posed here. Thank you for your time.